Tkinter: widgets are enclosed in white rectangles
My app has a background and various widgets. Unfortunately, these widgets are enclosed in white rectangles. I want these white rectangles to be transparent so that the background image of the app is visible through them. I couldn't find a working solution from other sources.

Can you post a screenshot of the white rectangles that you want to remove? Also have you tried setting the border and highlightthickness to 0 when creating the widgets? A [mre] would be great to show what you have done and what exactly the problem is

Tkinter widgets do not support transparent background.  You can use a Canvas widget as the background, and put images and text on it because those support transparency.

You could match the background color with the background color of the frames?
